# Showing multiple reports in one Dashboard without summarizing it

Tags: reporting, dashboard

I have multiple reports that I want to show in one dashboard without summarizing it. For example, 'Open Opportunities with old closed dates' or 'Contacts with no email ID' would be reports that I would put into a 'Warnings Dashboard'. I don't want to summarize these reports but rather show this data all in one page.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You sort of have 3 options here from easiest to implement from most difficult:

1) Use the Table Component for your Dashboard.  This component only works for reports that have some sort of grouping.  You may not be able to get the full data you want this way.

2) Create a Visualforce page that essentially uses frames to link the various reports in the Windows.

3) Create a Visualforce page that manually builds all of the reports that you needs and then displays them in the form that you desire.